# Simple Visual Comparison of Horizontal Lines of Different Length

Tags: plot, bar-chart, horizontal-line

Given an array with different length values, how can I plot something like this?

[image]

- The range of the values is 10-10000
- The visual simplicity would be important

From your experience, how could I visualize this efficiently?
Is that possible with such large differences in length?
Is Python the right programming language? If so, which package would I use?

I'd appreciate advice!